# Differentiability for $\sin(x) \leqslant f(x) \leqslant x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and let $\sin(x) \leqslant f(x) \leqslant x$ for every $x \in [0, \frac\pi2]$ and $f(-x) = -f(x)$ when $x \in [0, \frac\pi2]$. Show that $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

So I know that in order to show differentiability we can use the definition of derivative (difference quotient), but how can we apply that here? It seems to me that the Squeeze theorem could also be of help in this particular example?

Comment: It's false: take $f(0)=0$, $f(x)=1$ if $x \neq 0$.

Comment: Ah, damn. Instead of $x$ i wrote $1$. Should be fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write down the limit that calculates the derivative from the right, and then apply the given inequality, the squeeze theorem should be your friend here.

Is that enough of a hint, or would you prefer to see more details?

Comment: Hmm, this results in $\lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{f(x) - f(0)}{x}$, but we don't know $f(0)$ right?

Comment: Sure you know $f(0)$. Your condition states that $f$ is between $\sin(x)$ and $x$ on an interval that includes $0$, so it can only be one thing.

Comment: Well $ 0 \leqslant \sin(x) \leqslant 1$ so therefore $1 \leqslant f(x) \leqslant 1$? Hence $f(0) = 1$?

Comment: You have $\sin 0 \le f(0) \le 0$, or just look at the graphs of $\sin x$ and $x$.

Comment: Hmm, somehow i don't see this now. Where did you get the right-hand side for $\sin(0) \leqslant f(0) \leqslant 0$? Shouldn't it be $\sin(0) \leqslant f(0) \leqslant 1$

Comment: It's literally just the inequality in your question, with $0$ plugged in for $x$. You have $\sin(x)\le f(x)\le x$. Replace all three of those $x$'s with $0$'s. You can do that because you stated that the inequality holds for all $x$ in $[0,1]$, and $x=0$ is in that interval.

Comment: Ah, now i feel dumb for not seeing this... So now that we have $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ we can extend this to the given inequality and since $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x} = 1$  by L'Hospital we have by Squeeze theorem that $\lim_{x\to0} \frac{f(x)}{x} = 1$ so $f'(0) = 1$. Is it safe to just use $0$ and not look at the limits from both sides here?

Comment: The argument you just made works for the right-sided limit, because that's the only place we're given that our inequality holds. To cover the left side, you use the fact that $f$ is odd to "factor out" the minus sign. To be more clear, the limit as x goes to 0 from the left of $f(x)/x$ can be written as the limit of $\frac{-f(x)}{-x}$, which is the same as $\frac{f(-x)}{-x}$, which *is* the right-hand limit you already calculated, because the opposites of numbers just to the left of zero are precisely numbers just to the right of zero.